# How to find out which days the Chinese embassy/consulate in Kuala lumpur is open?

Tags: china, kuala-lumpur, embassies, consulates

I'm planning to get a visa for China while I'm in Kuala Lumpur soon, but I discovered I'll be arriving during a major Muslim holiday period, [Hari Raya Puasa (Eid al-Fitr)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eid_ul-Fitr#Malaysia).

I know consulates and embassies can have very restricted and strange opening times and that they're usually closed at least for holidays in both the home country and the host country, but as I have no idea which days those are for China or Malaysia I tried to find directly from the KL embassy/consulate web site which days it is open or closed.

So far I can't find this information. I'd like to know the days for August 2013 or even better a web page with the info.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that you will be fine and the embassy/consulate is open in August 2013. According to the [official website of Chinese embassy in Malaysia](http://my.china-embassy.org/eng/lsfws/t1001037.htm):

> PLEASE BE KINDLY INFORMED THAT THE CONSULAR SECTION OF THE CHINESE EMBASSY WILL BE CLOSED DURING THE FOLLOWING CHINESE HOLIDAYS.
>
> New Year’s Day January 1-3
>
> Spring Festival February 9-15
>
> Qingming Festival April 4-6
>
> Int'l Labor Day April 29 - May 1
>
> Dragon Boat Festival June 10-12
>
> Mid-autumn Festival September 19-21
>
> National Day October 1-7

I still think this information is missing the national holidays for Malaysia. Usually embassies respect the host countries and stop working on the host's country holidays. So I think they won't be working on August (7-9) depending on the end of the lunar month of Ramadan.

[For future reference for the coming years](http://my.china-embassy.org/eng/lsfws/).

Comment: Ah yes I see Hari Raya Puasa is the Malay name for Eid al-Fitr, which is in the answer I found. My Malaysian friend mad me think this would be nearer August 1 when I arrive but it looks like I could get my visa before Eid if I'm lucky.

Answer (score 2):

Well with a bit more persistent searching I did find this information on [a third-party website](http://www.travelchinaguide.com/embassy/malaysia.htm), so I don't think it's official:

> ```
> 2013 Holiday Schedule of CVASC in Kuala Lumpur 
> Public Holiday                   |Date             |Day
> ---------------------------------+-----------------+----------------
> New Year's Day                   |January 1        |Tuesday
> Prophet Muhammad's Birthday      |January 24       |Thursday
> Thaipusam                        |January 27, 28   |Sunday, Monday
> Federal Territory Day            |February 1       |Friday
> Spring Festival                  |February 10 - 12 |Sunday - Tuesday
> International Labor Day          |May 1            |Wednesday
> Wesak Day                        |May 24           |Friday
> Yang di-Pertuan Agong's Birthday |June 1           |Saturday
> Hari Raya Puasa                  |August 8, 9      |Thursday, Friday
> National Day                     |August 31        |Saturday
> The Malaysia Day                 |September 16     |Monday
> Hari Raya Qurban                 |October 15       |Tuesday
> Deepavali                        |November 2       |Saturday
> Awal Muharram                    |November 5       |Tuesday
> Christmas Day                    |December 25      |Wednesday
> ```